# How to use output of complete LSTM sequence ? tensorflow

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning

I might be wrong here but here goes.
I'm using the code in this [post](https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/examples/3%20-%20Neural%20Networks/recurrent_network.py).

Specifically the code in

```
    outputs, states = rnn.rnn(lstm_cell, _X, initial_state=_istate)

    # Linear activation
    # Get inner loop last output
    return tf.matmul(outputs[-1], _weights['out']) + _biases['out']
```

The code above uses the many to one prediction scheme.

[image]

I would like to know if I could use the many to many scheme with this code.
And the use the outputs of all the LSTM units to predict the class.
I have tried replacing the last line with

```
return tf.matmul(outputs, _weights['out']) + _biases['out']
```

But then I get an error

```
  File "/media/anilil/Data/charm/Cnn/train_lstm_ucf.py", line 165, in <module>
    pred = RNN(x, istate, weights, biases,keep_prob)
  File "/media/anilil/Data/charm/Cnn/train_lstm_ucf.py", line 163, in RNN
    return tf.matmul(outputs, _weights['out']) + _biases['out']
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py", line 938, in matmul
    a = ops.convert_to_tensor(a, name="a")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 529, in convert_to_tensor
    ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/constant_op.py", line 178, in _constant_tensor_conversion_function
    return constant(v, dtype=dtype, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/constant_op.py", line 161, in constant
    tensor_util.make_tensor_proto(value, dtype=dtype, shape=shape))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py", line 319, in make_tensor_proto
    _AssertCompatible(values, dtype)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py", line 256, in _AssertCompatible
    raise TypeError("List of Tensors when single Tensor expected")
TypeError: List of Tensors when single Tensor expected
```

## Background info (Non- vital)

Thanks for your input. I'm not sure myself if this approach would yield better results.

I'm trying to replicate [this paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1411.4389v3.pdf) 
Specifically the [activity recognition](http://jeffdonahue.com/lrcn/) from this paper.

What they do is train a CNN with a single frame to predict which class the frame belongs to and then use the the dense layer features of this to train an LSTM and hence understanding the temporal relation between the single frames and improve the recognition accuracy.

I have reproduced the results with the CNN and get an single frame accuracy (table 1:-  RGB singleframe)accuracy of 61%.

I have extracted the (fc-6)features from this network and given it as an input to the LSTM but instead of an improvement in accuracy to ~71.2% I get the LSTM accuracy of 51% which is reduced. Not sure why this happens. (possibly the LSTM model they used was different is my guess)

Any thoughts on that appreciated as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the list of all the outputs, you can do the following:

```
return [tf.matmul(output, _weights['out']) + _biases['out'] for output in outputs]
```

This will return a python array of TensorFlow tensors, one per output.

If instead you want a tensor that concatenates all the outputs, pass this array to `tf.concat`:

```
transformed_outputs = [tf.matmul(output, _weights['out']) + _biases['out'] for output in outputs]
return tf.concat(concat_dim=0, values=transformed_outputs)
```

Note that here I use `concat_dim=0`. If you process multiple inputs per batch (which is less common for RNNs I guess?), then your 0th dimension is sample ID, and you will need to use `concat_dim=1`.

Comment: Very elegant answer! Did you ever try this: combining all outputs for class prediction? I wonder this can actually improve the prediction performance in general.

Comment: I myself did not, but I know people who aggregate results from different timesteps together instead of just getting the class from the last step, and I don't believe it produces any noticeable improvement.
Anyway, I think in the OP case he actually has a problem that requires one output per timestep, so it's not just an optimization for him, but rather a requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Please note that the `outputs` is a list not a tensor.

It's an interesting idea, and it's up to you how to combine the outputs. One simple way might be:

```
return tf.matmul(outputs[1], W[1]) + tf.matmul(outputs[2], W[2]) ...
```

(Use the list comprehension or something.)

I am not sure this can improve the prediction results, but interesting to see.